# Request MultiPart/Form-Data with ByteArray

Tags: java, httprequest

i want to send a request includes bytearray as form-data. Everyone using "File" but i have just the "bytearray" and i don't want to use any path. My request in curl:

```
curl -F file=@file server
```

In java what i tried:

```
byte[] fileByte = Base64.decodeBase64(parameter);
ByteArrayInputStream myFile = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByte);
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("server");

multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", myFile, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "filename");

HttpEntity multipart = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(multipart);
```

and i tried

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", fileByte, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "filename");

//OR FileBody, ByteArrayEntity, InputStream or like thats
```

So, that methods not worked for me. How i can send the request successfully ?

EDIT: **i used the ptsv2 with postman and result ->** [image]

**when i send the same request and file with java the result** -> [image]

i think issue is certainly related to the ByteArray or InputStream. I must find the another Type for the my byte[] or right method for post in java with using the File type but without path.

Comment: What does "not worked for me" mean? What behavior do you get when you run your code with each of these two alternatives?

Comment: file / byte not reach to server successfully. example: i send to 1000kb file but i get the 1b as broken on the server. *curl working properly.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try posting to a test server, like https://ptsv2.com/s/whatisthis.html, just to get a clean and impartial look at what your request is sending, to rule out the problem being with whatever you are sending to now.  That's what I do in the answer I provided.  In that answer, I sent a very simple text string.  I don't have your data, so you could try sending that and see that it works too.  It should, as binary data is binary data.

Comment: I just noticed that you're trying to send a fairly large file.  Maybe you shouldn't send all of that data to the ptsv2.com test server.  Maybe you can just send 1K instead of 1M.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Comment: Have you checked the size of the byte array that you get from `Base64.decodeBase64(parameter)`?  Print that out or show it in the debugger.  Maybe the problem is right there, and the rest of the code is working fine.  I'm still thinking that it shouldn't matter what's in `fileByte`, so I'm guessing that the array isn't right in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "server" is, but maybe the problem is with the server you are sending to.  I ran your code, writing to a public HTTP POST test server available on the internet, and it works fine for me.  Here's the code I ran:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class ListsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] fileByte = "Sample string data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://ptsv2.com/t/r7ypk-1613291354/post");

        multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", fileByte, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "filename");

        HttpEntity multipart = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

        try {
            client.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you go to the target test server bucket:

```
https://ptsv2.com/t/r7ypk-1613291354
```

you can see what the full request looks like as received by the server, and see that the payload makes it over just fine as a file with the appropriate filename and contents.  The file content portion of the request display looks like this:

[image]

Your alternate method worked equally well for me.  I chose to post this version as it is simpler, not requiring you to wrap your byte array in an InputStream object.

Comment: i tried again and added results to the my first post through edit. By the way, thanks for the ptsv2 dump :) it is useful website and bookmarked now by me